# Apache Flink REST API

Tags: api, rest, apache-flink

Apache Flink provides a set of Rest API. When my flink job is running, I tried to access the job using /jobs and it gave me the metadata information. When i tried to fetch the results using /job/:jobid/execution-result, I got the result as {status: "RUNNING"}. Upon stopping I get the response as

{
"status": {
"id": "COMPLETED"
},
"job-execution-result": {
"id": jobid,
"application-status": "CANCELED",
"accumulator-results": {},
"net-runtime": 1872358
}
}

Is there a way I can get the results that get printed on flink std out using any other API calls?